Can you fill puff pastry with a cooked meat filing 12 hrs before baking
Can you fill puff pastry with a cooked meat filling 12 hrs before baking. I

maybe, but it's going to suffer.  is this a completely encased item, like a hand pie, or more cups of dough?  If they're cups, you might be able to do something like blind bake them, the pipe in the filling and give them a final bake just before serving

I would not do it due to the moisture of the meat. The moisture of the meat could potentially make the pastry soggy from the juices.
If you wanted to prep and do ahead of time, i would shape, fill and do freezer right away. Filling must be cold too. But then your bake times and stuff would be different.
I did something with filled ravioli, and it ended up being soggy on the bottoms and ruined the whole dinner. I prepped, filled and put in the fridge. All gone the next day. Super sad.
Last but not least, the puff pastry will rise too so its all relative in a way.

Yes you can fill puff pastry 12 hours before baking if you:

Cool the meat filling completely first Store in the fridge, covered
Add egg wash just before baking
Plan for extra baking time since pastry will be cold

For best results, don't store longer than 24 hours to avoid soggy pastry.

Absolutely! Just be sure to refrigerate (or freeze) it as soon as possible and bring to room temperature before cooking. The best way to do this is by taking it out of the refrigerator 30 minutes or so before cooking--like while your oven is warming up--and letting it sit on the counter (unless you have the kind of cats I do).
As one respondent mentioned, the only concern here is not to store it too long. You want to avoid soggy pastry. Good luck!
